# "Qu'est ce qui te fait le dire" vs "ce qui te fait le dire"

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

"Qu'est ce qui te fait le dire" vs "ce qui te fait le dire" means "what do you mean" but which is correct?

Are both correct or is "ce qui te fait le dire" a segment of a complete thought?

Answer (score 2):

Neither means "what do you mean" (*Qu'est-ce que tu veux dire ?*).

The first one, "*Qu'est-ce qui te fait le dire ?*" can't be but a question: "What makes you say it?"

The second one, "*Ce qui te fait le dire*", is a statement and is usually a part of a whole sentence like "*C'est ce qui te fait le dire*": "It is what makes you say it".

The register is formal/literary, although *Qu'est-ce qui te le fait dire* is even more.

In spoken French, you most likely hear:

*Qu'est-ce qui te fait dire ça ?* / *Ce qui te fait dire ça*